# Android align image button one by one and scrollable

Tags: android

I have 4 image buttons, and will add more later. I want to add them one by one and each one is below the previous one. Therefore, I created a `ScrollView`, so that it is scrollable to view all buttons. But after I add the `ScrollView`, I cannot move other elements.

Here is my codes:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.exampl.mygames.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/btntower"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/btntower"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/btntower"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/btntower"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: If they  are to align after each other, use a linearlayout and `android:gravity="center"` on the imageButtons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below layout:

add `android:fillViewport="true"` and change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in `scrollview`

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.exampl.mygames.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: still the same, they are overlapping

Comment: hi sir, but the last button cannot be shown completely, so I wound if you could fix it too please?

Comment: in the last image button add `android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"`

Comment: Thanks again, sir!